# Which one should I use cancan or authlogic to only authenticate the admin folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have a rails 2.3.8 application that has an admin folder that if anyone enters

```
/admin/anything
```

they need to be prompted for a login...I was looking for a good approach to do this

here the resources I was looking at [authorization](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization.html) and [authentication](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication.html)

The way I was thinking was to install authlogic or cancan or both or neither....not sure if anyone has a better solution. BTW I dont want authentication anywhere on the site

Comment: Have you considered authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic  or authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest ? This is probably the fastest way to provide basic protection for your application. See http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication for a complete example.

Comment: You don't need cancan here, authorization is when you need certain authenticated users to be able to do something, but certain user not able to do something. Like a user can delete a post if he created it or if he is moderator, but no other user can delete a post.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to have all controllers under the `admin/` namespace inherit from  an AdminController with a before_filter that handles authorization

The simplest way to do this is to use http_basic authentication ([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication))

If you want multiple user/passwords, but without the complexity of devise/authlogic, try nifty_authentication (via ryan bates' [nifty generators](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators/))

Answer (score 0):

As ruby-toolbox indicates, CanCan and Devise are the most popular authorization / authentication solutions for rails. Check out the always excellent **railscasts.com** episodes to get started:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

Railscasts is a fantastic resource for quickly getting up to speed on rails topics.

Comment: yes i know that but first off devise is only rails 3 and I dont see a way to set a username and password with cancan

Comment: my mistake you can use devise with rails 2.3.8